# How to generate code that uses Android APIs

Tags: java, android, code-generation, annotation-processing

I have a java library that generates code for our Android project.
We are using this to lower the amount of code we need to write in some of our `RecyclerView` adapters. 
The issue I ran into is that the annotation processor can't depend on the Android framework, which is quite limiting, because we need to reference some Android SDK classes while generating the code.

```
public interface FeedModuleManager {
     ViewHolder create(ViewGroup parent, int viewType);
}
```

The annotation processor generates implementations of above interface. (there are more methods, I took that out for brevity)

What I did is that I created stubbed out versions of those classes (`ViewGroup` and `ViewHolder`), but it's causing some issues here and there across our build and tooling stack.

So I'm looking for some better way how to do this..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such libraries, for all I know. There is a [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet), but it generates the code exactly as you specify. But in no way do for example the implementation of all methods of a specific interface. Most likely this decision will have to be programmed.

Comment: I use Javapoet to generate the code and indeed I wrote the logic what code to generate. The issue I had is that the code references classes from Android framework (and other libs that depend on Android) which is not accessible from inside of the processor.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Then, I can not help here anymore. However, in this situation, I would take the classes and packages that I needed with the Android SDK.